# UserControl: Best Method of Saving Values/Preferences

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I've created a UserControl which is basically a panel with various controls used for setting user preferences and values (e.g. age, height, male/female, ..., textbox, radio button, checkbox, ...) and it is used on the primary WinForm application. I'm looking for the "best" or easiest method of saving the user's selections so they are kept on the next application load.

If the controls were on the primary WinForm I'd use the Properties.Settings method (but there are a lot of them and I didn't want to do this). I also considered creating save/load methods and using XML serialization but this would require ~40 properties to be created and updated. I'm ok with doing the XML method but figured I'd ask you nice folks to see if there was a simpler method I was unaware of.

Thanks!

Comment: Properties.Settings and XML type serialization are custom designed for this exact purpose. Why do people always want to hack around the easy options? The other alternative would be to save to a database, but that is more effort. It can't really get any easier than Properties.Settings.

Comment: @GlenThomas Hence why I asked the question. I was familiar with both methods and had used them in the past for saving smaller sets of preferences but thought I'd ask if there was another method (e.g. something like Properties.Settings but for UserControls) I was unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a combination of serialization and data binding is the way to go, just create a class that contains all the settings you want to save, bind them to the controls, serialize and save them when you exit the form and load them when you load the form :

```
_settings = new Settings()
{
    Name = "Name",
    Name1 = "Name1",
    Name2 = "Name2"
};
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _settings, "Name");
textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", _settings, "Name1");
textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", _settings, "Name2");
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
   using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite("settings.xml"))
   {
       ser.Serialize(stream, _settings);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot. Looks nice.